# Java - Can Calendar.getInstance() be used to differentiate past and future events

Tags: java, calendar

I have an `Event` class. I am using a `GregorianCalendar` to store the date of the Event. If I want to find which events have already occurred before today and which events are in the future, does `Calendar.getInstance()` give the present date which I can then use to compare?

Comment: Have you consulted [its docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance())?

Comment: Yes, but you probably shouldn't use `Calendar` for this purpose.  It is expensive and mutable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`Calendar.before()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before(java.lang.Object)) and [`Calendar.after()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after(java.lang.Object)). Like So:

```
if(Calendar.getInstance().before(myEvent)){
   // do before stuff
} else if(Calendar.getInstance().after(myEvent)) {
   // do after
} else {
   // do right now
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken off the first search https://www.google.com/search?q=Calendar.getInstance()

> Like other locale-sensitive classes, Calendar provides a class method, getInstance, for getting a generally useful object of this type. Calendar's getInstance method returns a Calendar object whose calendar fields have been initialized with the current date and time:

```
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
```